# Cordova link broken. Where to find it?

Tags: cordova

I am trying to get started with Android and PhoneGap (setting up development environment) [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android).

While getting resources for installing SDK + Cordova, I was given a link that doesn't work.
(http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/#download)

Where else can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find Cordova projects at https://github.com/apache

Comment: Ok, I guess it would be cordova-android.. Thank's!